# List is unclickable in webpage. Any suggestions on what may be going wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a html list that displays a QR when an option is selected. The list can be automatically updated and reads the link to the QR from a text file.

List HTML :

```
<label id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();"> </label>
```

JS for Both:

Update List Function:

```
// The following function Automatically updates the list presented in the webpage
function updateList(text)
{
    var arr = text.split("\n") /*every new line is a new bullet point*/

    for(var i in arr) {

    var option = document.createElement("option");

        var content = arr[i].split("*")
        option.text = content[0];
        console.log(option.text); 
        option.value = content[1];
        console.log(option.value);
        var select = document.getElementById("myList");
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Displaying the QR Code:

```
function setPicture()
{
    var dv = document.getElementById('qrcode');

    while (dv.hasChildNodes()) { 
        dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild); 
    } // clear previous qr code
    var list = document.getElementById('myList');
    //point to url and pass to qrGen function

    var link = list.options[list.selectedIndex].value; 

    console.log(link);

    qrGen(link);
}
```

Opens Text File in Drive from Selected option on Webpage List:

```
function openText(file)
{

    var allText = '';
    $("div").append("<ul></ul>");
    var buffer = new XMLHttpRequest();
    buffer.open("GET", file, false);
    buffer.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(buffer.status == 200 && buffer.readyState == 4){
        allText = buffer.responseText;
        }    
    };
    buffer.send(null);
    updateList(allText)
}
```

QR Code Generation:

```
function qrGen(link)
{
{
new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), link); 
}
}
```

Comment: 2 things. 1.You forgot to ask a question. 2. You added the onchage event on a label.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the pointer! I will change it to a question for clarity.

Comment: Yes, I just read onchange event can only be added to select and input tags. however, both tags result in functionalities I wouldn't want. i.e, select tag creates a drop down menu and input tag allows input box. Do you have a suggestion on another way I could maintain the onchnage functionality? I am a little new to web development

Comment: You can add multiple onchange event on a select tag.

Comment: @Ibu would you possibly give an example? I don't clearly understand it